# Making Yes or No question in exe using pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I'm currently making the exe using pyinstaller, and I'd like to insert Y/N question inside.

I'm currently using:

```
msvcrt.getch()
```

for this, but this is just a click anything to continue type text.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tkinter?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# this is required to hide GUI window
tk.Tk().withdraw()

MsgBox = tk.messagebox.askquestion('Info', 'Have you tried tkinter?', icon = 'warning')
if MsgBox == 'yes':
    ...
else
    ...
```